# Anaconda Spyder keeps crashing after a while

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I am new and learning Python and its development tools, so please help me to resolve following issue.

I have googled the error over and over but I fail to find a solution to my exact  error. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing twice with no success.

I am using Anaconda's Spyder IDE and whenever I leave my PC unattended for a bit and I return, I am presented with the following crash error:

[image: Python_crash_error]

The result is that Python becomes unresponsive and I am forced to restart.

Please note that everything else is working fine; it is merely this annoying crash.

Comment: I am facing same problem in Windows 10. Did you get any solution?